# Adobe Illustrator questions are prohibited now?

Tags: discussion

Previously I was asking Adobe Illustrator qeustions here and everything was well. Recently I have asked one new innocent question on Adobe Illustrator and it was poorly received by the community:

[image]

Are Adobe Illustrator questions are prohibited now? In [rules](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I see that only video editing software questions are prohibited.

Comment: The comments at Super User shed light on why the migration was rejected: http://superuser.com/questions/915191/adobe-illustrator-does-not-draw-wire-line-during-pencil-drawing?noredirect=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends upon the question. Application troubleshooting is technical support and generally off topic. Asking how to create something within Illustrator is generally on-topic though.

Each question is unique. Illustrator questions aren't inherently off-topic. However if you ask how to fix an error or how an application functions, it may be seen as technical support.

This may explain further: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2600/3270

Comment: How to distinguish between bug and feature if you don't know an answer?

Comment: It's fairly simple... "This tool/feature/command doesn't do what I want it to do or what it used to do...." Is application support. Compared to.... "I don't know how to create this...." If you are seeking to solve a problem with an *application* and how it operates, chances are it's tech support and off topic. If you are seeking to solve a problem with *workflow* or in creating something, then it's probably on-topic.

Comment: Any question "tool doesn't do smth" can be reformulated as "how to do smth with the tool".

Comment: I disagree @Dims How would you reword your question regarding the pencil tool preview? Any word structure is still going to mean the answer is "ask Adobe tech support" or "reset preferences" or Reinstall the application -- all tech support. Just because common design software is in use, it doesn't automatically make the question on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question it is a Technical Support issue which is why Yisela wanted to migrate it to SuperUser.

A Design question would involve actual design, not how to configure software to work as intended. Your previous questions are questionable, and borderline on "Simple "How to" questions"

I do thank you for bringing this up, I've never seen that exact page of our How-To and do think our Moderators need to clarify it. **As a community we've decided Technical Issues are not on topic. As per: [What do we want to be off-topic as Tech Support?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/what-do-we-want-to-be-off-topic-as-tech-support)**

P.S. For a possible solution to your issue see: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/786263?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Okay, you explained why Yisela sent a question to SuperUser. Now explain why SuperUser people didn't accept it :)

Comment: Thats a question for superuser.  We cannot nor will we control another sites scope.  If you would like to know as on their meta site.