# Area51 Proposal: Beginner Graphic Design Stack Exchange (working title)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderation, moderators, quality-evaluation

## How do we reduce tutorial-on-demand and basic/beginner questions?

### Answer: We push them to Beginner Graphic Design SE <sup>(working title)</sup>

- **Our Motto: We teach them how to fish instead of giving them a fish.**

  *(This way they don't keep coming back to us)*
- No more close votes. Mods with their magic mod powers can just push the question to Graphic Design 101 SE.
- This might not be a hard sell at Area51 considering how strong opinions are here at this moment. I believe we could get enough followers to get the Area51 higher ups to recognize the benefit.

---

## Have an idea for a better working title?

### Suggest it along with you answer! :)

<sup>**NOTE!!!:**  (The title is very important! The title is the first impression and be the major deciding factor for rejection. It has to be something that "newbs" automatically recognize they should go to instead of GDSE)</sup>

---

**I haven't proposed anything yet, but If I did, here's a really ugly draft of what it would look like.**
[image]

In response to:

<sup>[What to do with tutorial requests? -- part II](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii)</sup>

<sup>[Changing how we handle low-effort and tutorial-on-demand questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/changing-how-we-handle-low-effort-and-tutorial-on-demand-questions)</sup>

<sup>[Why do how-to requests bother you?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/why-do-how-to-requests-bother-you)</sup>

Comment: Why the down vote? Constructive criticism please. If you have an opinion share it.

Comment: I'm not a regular on here at all so I shouldn't voice my biased thought, but consider reading a similar discussion on Meta Stack Overflow of why SO is not split into 2 sites: [Why are there “beginner” and “advanced” English sites on the SE network, but not for programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266443/why-are-there-beginner-and-advanced-english-sites-on-the-se-network-but-not) and its duplicate link to see the pros & cons.

Comment: @AndrewT. I think it's as valid of an idea as Code Review SE. Which at glance doesn't fit the SE site model

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this proposal (tho' I'm also not staunchly opposed to it), but perhaps title it "Drawing Class" ? Drawing – heh heh – on the two meanings of 'class'. No relation to the medieval execution style implied.

Answer (score 13):

I hate this idea and downvoted it. Sorry.

To try and elaborate I did go back through Ink Spot and read the conversation about this starting roughly https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42984530#42984530.

What it ultimately comes down to is all of the things you want to migrate are on-topic and will remain on-topic here. Beginner is subjective and really not the issue at all. The issue is that the people complaining don't actively vote to close as too broad when applicable or ask and promote good questions. Everything I've read from others says their problem is the ratio of questions they view as interesting to the ratio of questions they view as boring.

I'll use myself as an example - I feel fairly confident I'm one of the most experienced people here particularly in photo manipulation and editing. Things that are incredibly basic to me aren't to even some of our other experienced users. Likewise, something that Joojaa or Scott may find very basic in illustration would be moderate to advanced to me.

There really is no delineation between these premises. The deciding factors should always be:

1. Is this question defined enough that someone can answer it without writing a textbook. If not, vote to close as too broad.
2. Did this person answering explain their answer beyond "Press X to do Y."

Comment: I actually upvoted this. I agree with these points.

Comment: This x 1000000000

Comment: +1 ... I only remember some the things I know by answering the most basic of questions.....

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be focussing on splitting the questions, which indeed is technically easy, but Stack Exchange sites are about communities, not just about types of questions. More specifically:

- Who is going to answer these questions? How do they differ from this community?
- How will you keep contributors on the site?
- How will questions that are a problem on this site (too broad, lacking detail, no information where the asker comes from) not be a problem on your site? Or with other words: How will this actually solve the problem?

I am aware that something vaguely similar has been done with English Language & Usage (ELU) and English Language Learners (ELL), but:

- There actually is some inherent difference between the communities of those who learnt a language natively or have been exposed to it on a daily basis for years and those who are just learning it – there is no such thing as native graphic designers (with *native* as in *native speaker*).
- People on ELU are still complaining about non-challenging questions.
- ELL imposes rules against the typical questions that are the bane of all language sites as well (for example questions that could have been answered by a dictionary, proofreading, etc.).
- In my opinion, the ELU–ELL “split” is not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I think it's a good idea. I especially like the ethos "teach them to fish, instead of giving them a fish"

***Edit:*** The following section was in response to the previous suggested working title "Graphic Design 101 SE", which has now been changed.

Not so sure about the working title. It's very *American*.  The number 101 has a rather unfortunate connotation here in the UK - regarding George Orwell's Room 101, from his novel "1984". It's the place where all your worst nightmares live, the place to which you are sent when Big Brother thinks you've been naughty, the torture chamber of the Ministry of Love, for the correction of "thoughtcriminals", the place where Winston Smith goes to be gnawed by rats.

However, when I come to think of it, it might be rather apt!

Comment: XD I learned some new cultural info today. I'm reverting it back to name option #2

Comment: Okay you might want to edit your post now because I've changed the working title. Or you can leave it for historical purposes w/e :P

Comment: @LateralTerminal OK, made an edit, but also left it because it's quite funny.

Comment: and the slightly less sinister (although inspired by the same) [room 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_101_(TV_series))